# Host Machine Requirment for Gemfire 9.8.4

Tags: gemfire

If i am using Gemfire Client-Server topology, does my client machines need to meet the Gemfire Host Machine Requirement (https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/98/gemfire/getting_started/system_requirements/host_machine.html) ? Is it only for Gemfire Servers and Locators? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question would be yes, those [Host Machine Requirements](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/98/gemfire/getting_started/system_requirements/host_machine.html) are needed for any GemFire application (either client, locator or server).

Cheers.

Comment: How about window OS? What do I need to care? Is it only jdk version and time synchronization ?